# Should we use a canonical tag even if we are sure the page doesn't have any duplicate?

Tags: seo, googlebot, rel-canonical

If my pages don't have any duplicates, and their URLs are all clean (no '?id=123456' stuff), should I still use canonical tags? (from a SEO perspective)

In other words, would bots downgrade me (or not even index my pages) for not using them, if they are not directly needed?

Comment: How can you be sure there are no duplicates?   You mention you don't use query query parameters, but what do you do if a link to your site adds a query parameter?  Do you redirect to remove it?  Do you show a 404 error?   How do you deal with `index.html` URLs?   Do you deal with HTTP vs HTTPS?   Do you deal with `www` vs `no-www`?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller,I guess you are right, I have some of those under control, but not all them. I'll add the canonical tags to be on the safe side :) thanks.